# Get unread message count from delegated maibox

Tags: google-apps-script, google-admin-sdk

I am looking for a method to find the unread message count of delegated mailboxes from any of the Google API's.

I am not sure IF it is possible, but it would help me develop a helping tool for a company using this for 1000+ users. A lot of delegation is going on, and I am eager to find a way to accomplish this.

But I might need some help, maybe from people closer with knowledge of the possibilities of the Admin SDK from Google.

I want to use Google Apps Script to collect the unread message count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer from the GAS community on Google Plus, so credits to the posters there.

https://plus.google.com/106333172328928589411/posts/7g3Vu7iFZfb

Sergii: 
Check out this gist that shows how to do 2-legged OAuth authentication in GAS https://gist.github.com/rcknr/c5be4eb80d821158c8ef.﻿

Using 2 Legged Oauth you can get access to the ATOM feed of other users:

A piece of working code for it:

```
function gmail2lo(user) {
 var OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET = 'secret';
  var domain = 'domain'; //use the domain as key in apps panel
  var username = 'user';
  var xuser = username+'@'+domain;
  var method = "GET";
  var baseUrl = "https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom";

  var timestamp = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000);  

  var paramsJson;
  var paramsOauth = {
    oauth_consumer_key : domain,
    oauth_nonce : timestamp,
    oauth_signature_method : "HMAC-SHA1",
    oauth_timestamp : timestamp,
    oauth_version : "1.0",
    'xoauth_requestor_id' : xuser
  };

  var paramsStringArray =  [];
  for (var k in paramsJson)
    paramsStringArray.push(k + '=' + encodeURIComponent(paramsJson[k]));

  var oauthStringArray = [];  
  for (var k in paramsOauth)
    oauthStringArray.push(k + '=' + encodeURIComponent(paramsOauth[k]));

  var paramsString = paramsStringArray.concat(oauthStringArray).sort().join('&');
  var signatureBaseString = method +"&"+ encodeURIComponent(baseUrl) +"&"+ encodeURIComponent(paramsString);
  var signatureBytes = Utilities.computeHmacSignature(Utilities.MacAlgorithm.HMAC_SHA_1, signatureBaseString, OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET+'&');
  var signature = encodeURIComponent(Utilities.base64Encode(signatureBytes));

  var xoauthString = 'OAuth ' + oauthStringArray.sort().slice(0,oauthStringArray.length-1).join(", ") + ', oauth_signature=' + signature;

  var ooptions = {
    headers : {authorization: xoauthString}
  }

  url  = baseUrl;
  url += "?" + paramsStringArray.join("&") + '&xoauth_requestor_id=' + encodeURIComponent(xuser);

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, ooptions).getContentText();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Email Settings API allows you to [see which delegations are in place](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-settings/#retrieving_all_gmail_delegates).

It is not possible for a user to access the mailbox of another user who has delegated them access via IMAP, thus you can't authenticate as a user and check the delegated mailbox.

You should use OAuth 2.0 Service Accounts to [authenticate to the mailboxes via IMAP](https://developers.google.com/gmail/xoauth2_protocol).

Once authenticated you can select the Gmail "All Mail" folder (or Inbox if you only want count for Inbox). and do a [Gmail search of "is:unread"](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap_extensions#extension_of_the_search_command_x-gm-raw) to determine how many unread messages the user has.

FYI, my [open-source](https://code.google.com/p/got-your-back/source/browse/) app, GYB can do just this. There is a [getting started guide for GYB](https://code.google.com/p/got-your-back/wiki/GettingStarted?tm=6). You'll also need to [setup the service account](https://code.google.com/p/got-your-back/wiki/GettingStarted?tm=6#Google_Apps_Business_and_Education_Admins%3a_Backup,_Restore_and_E). The command to get unread message count for all mail would be something like:

```
gyb --email delegated-mailbox@yourcompany.com --service-account your-service@account.com --action count --search "is:unread"
```

Comment: Thank you, that's the direction.
I forgot to mention one thing: I want to do it using Google Apps Script...

Comment: I'm not aware of any method to achieve this with Google Apps Script.